# postfix: custom relayhost for any-subdomain of a specific domain?

Tags: postfix

What is the right way to add a different relay for "from" email addresses with a specific domain and any subdomain for them? Or in other words, what am I doing wrong? How would you change postfix configuration to make it work?

This is an internal relay - not connected to the internet. The goal is to:

1. Send emails with "from" addresses `*@domainB.com` and `*@*.domainB.com` to a special relay dedicated to that domain (`smtp.domainB.com`), while:
2. Send everything else - to the default relay.

P.S. It's plain vanilla CentOS 7.7. Postfix 2.10.1. This `/etc/postfix/relay_maps` only works for the domain but not subdomains:

```
domainB.com      [smtp.domainB.com]:25
.domainB.com     [smtp.domainB.com]:25
```

(...and yes, I run the following after updating the file:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/relay_maps
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

)

P.P.S. Also, the following line was added to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_maps
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the option **sender_dependent_relayhost_maps** , this option is avalalabe since  Postfix 2.3 .

So the option is avalaible on CENTOS 7

```
root@test-cs-7 ~]# rpm -qa postfix
postfix-2.10.1-9.el7.x86_64
[root@test-cs-7 ~]# postconf  | grep ^sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
```

A very simple example :

add this section at the end of /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_dependent_relayhost
```

create a file **/etc/postfix/sender_dependent_relayhost** with this content :

```
/^boss@example\.com/    [192.168.8.2]
/^boss@example\.net/    [192.168.8.1]
/^.*@.*\.example\.com/  [192.168.8.3]
/^.*@.*\.example\.net/  [192.168.8.4]
/^.*@example\.net/  [192.168.8.2]
/^.*@example\.com/  [192.168.8.1]
/^.*@example\.net/  [192.168.8.2]
```

About option :

- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps

About prce table :

- http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the answer to the title question, in terms of the contents of `/etc/postfix/sender_dependent_relayhost`:

```/^\S+\@domainB\.com/     [smtp.domainB.com]:25
/^\S+\@\S+\.domainB\.com/        [smtp.domainB.com]:25```

... as it matches the domain and any subdomains of that domain - yet rules out most invalid email addresses, and escapes the period in the domain name.

Comment: I think you need to escape the period in the domain name. Also, if you want to answer the actual question about any subdomain of a specific domain, you might want to include that as well - see my previous comment.